# progress bar not working with page index changing event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

in first time page load. progress bar coming then gridview is loading . but in case of changing page index. progress bar is rotating continously but grid view is not coming. if i remove progress bar from css paging is working fine

**java script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function () { $("#spinner").fadeOut("slow"); }) 
        </script>
```

**css code**

```
#spinner {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url(images/loading45.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #ede9df;
}

 protected void GridCategoryWise_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillgridview();

    }
```

Comment: Can you please re-edit your description part. It's too much confusing your title say's **progress bar not working with page index changing event in asp.net** but in your description you have said **while change page index progress bar just displaying but not grid view displaying.** and later on you are have mentioned **In page load progress bar coming, but not in post back event.**. Can you be specific what working and what's not.

Comment: in first time page load. progress bar coming then gridview is loading . but in case of changing page index. progress bar is rotating continously but grid view is not coming. if i remove progress bar from css paging is working fine @SuprabhatBiswal

Comment: Does the developer console shows any error when page index is changed?